# Iterating through BeatifulSoup findAll list with missing values

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some information from a HTML code from a website. In the website there are companies and some informations about them. I need 'name', 'description', 'focus' and 'location' info for every company. Here is an example set of infos for one of the companies:

```html
<span class="search-type f-header">Exhibitor</span>
<h2 itemprop="name" class="search-name f-subheadline">A.M.I.</h2>
<h3 itemprop="address" class="search-attribute f-default">F - Saint Marcel
</h3>
<p itemprop="description" class="search-excerpt f-default">The A.M.I. Company manufactures indicator panels and alarm annunciator since 1976. They are used in environments with significant ...
</p>
<p itemprop="makesOffer" class="search-info f-default">Focus: On-site <strong>control</strong> panels for fieldbus systems
</p><span class="search-location f-default">Hall 12, Stand G40</span>
```

There are nearly 5000 companies in the website and I tried to narrow the results by doing some querying in the website and I got the results back not in a single page but rather in 46 different page with same url for all of them and 20 companies in each page. That is why I opened the pages one by one and copy their source code into a text file and then open that in python.And my python code to handle this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from requests import get
import csv
import pandas as pd

url_oku = open('hannover.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')

total = []
mid = []
companies = ['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']
descriptions = ['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']
locations = ['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']
focus = ['?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?']

for count,comp in enumerate(soup.find_all('h2', {'itemprop': 'name'})):
    companies[count]=(comp.text)

for count,desc in enumerate(soup.find_all('p',{'class': 'search-excerpt f-default'})):
    descriptions[count]=(desc.text)

for count,foc in enumerate(soup.find_all('p',{'class': 'search-info f-default'})):
    focus[count]=(foc.text.strip())

for count,loc in enumerate(soup.find_all('span',{'class': 'search-location f-default'})):
    locations[count]=(loc.text)

print(len(companies), len(descriptions), len(locations),len(focus))

for i in range(len(companies)):
    mid.append(companies[i])
    mid.append(descriptions[i])
    mid.append(focus[i])
    mid.append(locations[i])
    total.append(mid)
    mid = []

my_df = pd.DataFrame(total)
my_df.columns = ['Company', 'Descr.','Focus','Location']
print(my_df)
```

I create a list with 20 '?' to make sure every list have 20 elements in it and to avoid losing infos. But unfortunately, some infos are missing for some companies. Such as:

```html
<span class="search-type f-header">Exhibitor</span>
<h2 itemprop="name" class="search-name f-subheadline">STOCKO CONTACT</h2>
<h3 itemprop="address" class="search-attribute f-default">D - Wuppertal
</h3>
<p itemprop="description" class="search-excerpt f-default">... our products at a high quality level. Products that can be found equally in heating <strong>controls</strong>, drink dispensing machines ...
</p><span class="search-location f-default">Hall 9, Stand F69</span></a>
```

For example in this company the focus info is missing. When I use findall method it only finds the existed info and add it to the list without considering its position in the page or which company it belongs. When I iterate through the company names and add the infos to the list 'total', this leads to mismatch between companies and their infos when I create dataframe. 
[The excel output when there are missing infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC3BP.png)
As you can see in the picture when the focus info:

```html
<p itemprop="makesOffer" class="search-info f-default">
```

is missing for some companies I can not match the existed focus info with the related company.

Is there any possible way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following info is fetched here:

```
line = '''<span class="search-type f-header">Exhibitor</span>
<h2 itemprop="name" class="search-name f-subheadline">A.M.I.</h2>
<h3 itemprop="address" class="search-attribute f-default">F - Saint Marcel
</h3>
<p itemprop="description" class="search-excerpt f-default">The A.M.I. Company manufactures indicator panels and alarm annunciator since 1976. They are used in environments with significant ...
</p>
<p itemprop="makesOffer" class="search-info f-default">Focus: On-site <strong>control</strong> panels for fieldbus systems
</p><span class="search-location f-default">Hall 12, Stand G40</span>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')
print [values.text for values in soup.findAll("span")]
print [values.text for values in soup.findAll("h2")]
print [values.text for values in soup.findAll("h3")]
print [values.text for values in soup.findAll("p")]
```

---

```
#output:
[u'Exhibitor', u'Hall 12, Stand G40']
[u'A.M.I.']
[u'F - Saint Marcel\n']
[u'The A.M.I. Company manufactures indicator panels and alarm annunciator since 1976. They are used in environments with significant ...\n', u'Focus: On-site control panels for fieldbus systems\n']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how can I designate companies without  focus info and create a data frame in which some companies have the all infos but some does not.